# how to get mapping array when compact with thrust

Tags: cuda, thrust

I need to know what position each element is mapped to when compact with thrust.

For example:

```
arr:       5  2  -1  3  -1  6 -1  7
compacted: 5  2   3  6  7     --------------(remove all -1 element)
map Arr:   0  1  -1  2  -1  3 -1  4
```

**The mapping array**, here I mean the array indicating which position that each element is moved to, sorry I can't come up with a better name to describe this, I hope I made things clear.

Compact with thrust is easy but I'm wondering if I can get that mapping array while thrust is compacting.

Comment: By 'compacting'  do you mean removing the `-1` entries in the source array?

Comment: @m.s.  yes, sorry I should have added more description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following sequence of thrust calls can generate the desired mapping array.

The output for your example is:

```
compacted: 5 2 3 6 7 
map: 0  0 -1  0 -1  0 -1  0 
map: 0  0 -1 -1 -2 -2 -3 -3 
map: 0  1  1  2  2  3  3  4 
map: 0  1 -1  2 -1  3 -1  4
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <thrust/scan.h>
#include <thrust/scatter.h>
#include <thrust/remove.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/constant_iterator.h>

void print(const std::string& name, int* begin, int* end)
{
  std::cout << name << ": ";
  thrust::copy(begin, end, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout <<std::endl;
}

struct is_marker
{
  __host__ __device__
  bool operator()(const int x) const
  {
    return (x == -1);
  }
};

int main()
{
  const int N = 8;
  int arr[N] = {5,2,-1,3,-1,6,-1,7};

  int compacted[N] = {0};
  int* compacted_end = thrust::remove_copy(arr, arr+N, compacted, -1);
  print("compacted", compacted, compacted_end);

  int map[N] = {0};
  thrust::scatter_if(thrust::make_constant_iterator(-1), thrust::make_constant_iterator(-1)+N, thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), arr, map, is_marker());
  print("map", map, map+N);

  thrust::inclusive_scan(map, map+N, map);
  print("map", map, map+N);

  thrust::transform(map, map+N, thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), map, thrust::plus<int>());
  print("map", map, map+N);

  thrust::scatter_if(thrust::make_constant_iterator(-1), thrust::make_constant_iterator(-1)+N, thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), arr, map, is_marker());
  print("map", map, map+N);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Your approach certainly looks more efficient!

Comment: @RobertCrovella: You are always so great!  :-)